# How to change TextBox.text font style to Italic

Tags: vb.net, winforms, textbox

I have a textbox control called `tb_remarks` and tried to make texts written in `tb_remarks` using:

`tb_remark.Font.Italic = True`, but I am getting a read only exception.

***Note***: I don't want to change the control's property using [Windows Forms Designer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/designers/walkthrough-windows-forms-designer)

Answer (score 4):

You should initialize a new style for the font as per [Control.Font Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.font.aspx) and assign [*italic*-style](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.fontstyle(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Imports System.Drawing

tb_remarks.Font = New Font(Font, FontStyle.Italic)
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`Font`-constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bdte89fc(v=vs.110).aspx) and assign it to the textbox:

```
Dim font = New Font(tb_remark.Font, FontStyle.Italic)
tb_remark.Font = font
```

By passing the old `Font` you use all other properties as prototype.